# Why doesn't instanceof narrow multicatch union types

Tags: java, generics

The sample function catches checked Exceptions A and B and throws A.
I expected the if statement with `instanceof` to unwind the union to the expected type, however I still need to cast it.

Is there a reason Java's type system can't/doesn't unwind the union type with instanceof?

```
public static void throwsA() throws ExceptionA {
    try {
        funThatThrowsAorB();
    } catch (ExceptionA | ExceptionB e) {
        // common code
        if (e instanceof ExceptionA) {
            throw e; // unhandled exception error
            throw (ExceptionA)e; // no problem
        } else {
            throw new ExceptionA(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll let one of the language lawyers answer this question authoritatively.  May I simply point out that programming languages, in general, execute statement by statement; Java doesn't really know about the `instanceof` in the line above it, unless you capture the knowledge present in that condition by either assigning it to a variable, or casting it as you have just done.

Comment: FYI, that is a very bad example of using multi-catch, since you immediately turn around and do `instanceof` check, in which case a separate `catch (ExceptionA e)` would have been much better, eliminating need for `instanceof` and for cast, without adding any duplicate code.

Comment: @Andreas this is just an mvp for the question. The real code does common logging and then `instanceof` + `throw`.

Comment: `instanceof` doesn't narrow types, and even if it did there is nothing in your syntax that would cause it to narrow `e`. Don't write code like this.

Comment: @user207421 how would you do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Java language never narrows a type when entering an if-statement (or any other conditional).

However, Java 14 introduced [pattern matching for instanceof expressions](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/305) as a preview feature:

```
if (obj instanceof String s) {
    // can use s here
} else {
    // can't use s here
}
```

As you can see, this introduces a new variable with the narrowed type, rather than narrowing the type of the existing variable. I am not certain why they chose that route, but I suspect backwards compatibility played a role. Specifically, if you simply narrow the type of an existing variable when entering a conditional, it might break existing code such as the following program:

```
Number number = 42;
if (number instanceof Integer) {
    number = 0.01 * number;
}
```

To fix that, you'd need to change the type of the variable not just when entering a conditional, but on any assignment. That's more complicated, but TypeScript shows that this is possible:

```
let x: number | string = "23";
if (typeof x === "string") {
    x.charAt(0); // x is a string here
    x = 3;
    x.toPrecision(2); // but a number here
}
```

I don't know why the Java design team disliked the TypeScript approach.

Comment: Thanks @meriton, this is a great explanation of why. Sadly I'm stuck with Java 11 so no pattern matching for me yet :'(

Answer (score 0):

Because when you are inside of the `catch` block, `e` is an instance of a capture type for both exceptions A and B. By casting, you are specifying that you are throwing `ExceptionA` specifically:

```
//e is an "instanceof" either ExceptionA or ExceptionB, but not specified yet!
//For now, e is simply the most specific shared parent type (Exception I assume)
ExceptionA eA; //Cannot be set to e! Cannot coerce Exception into ExceptionA
if (e instanceof ExceptionA) {
    eA = (ExceptionA) e; //Have to explicitly cast
    throw eA;
}
```

This works, because your method is specified to be capable of only throwing `ExceptionA`:

```
public static void throwsA() throws ExceptionA { ...
```

As far as why this is required, the error message from attempting an assignment is also pretty clear:
[image]

@Andreas offers a much more clear solution, which is just directly handling these errors individually:

```
try {
    //A or B exceptional code
} catch (ExceptionA eA) {
    throw eA;
} catch (ExceptionB eB) {
    //... B handling
}
```

Comment: I clarified the code, but the catch block is the same because both exceptions are handled the same way, there's just no need/use for the caller to know about ExceptionB.